# Realistic damage in 3.5/pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, gm-techniques, damage

As someone who is wont to forget things, here is my question:

I thought I remember reading articles/threads/posts/questions about more realistic ways to describe hit point loss. As in a narrative technique where real physical harm doesn’t really get described until you lose over half in one attack or you get down to your last 10% or so. Maybe off a forum or angrygm.com?

Does anyone know of this kind of gameplay I am trying to remember? Can you give a brief summary or provide a link to the source(s)?

(Not looking for mechanical rules, just a new narrative technique)

Comment: I downvoted the question for low-effort (you don't seem to have done any actual research before posting)

Comment: There are an *extraordinary* number of attempts to generate realistic damage for the classic RPG genre (especially Dungeons & Dragons), including coming with different narrative techniques. Most of them are obscure, or dead and forgotten. I'm closing this as too broad since unfortunately the details here aren't enough to narrow things down. The waters are probably a bit too muddied for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find suggestions about this on many places. Just with a quick search I came up with [a reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pathfinder_RPG/comments/4kckjz/more_realistic_rules_for_damage/) and [a giants in the playground thread](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-458096.html). The main points are often:

- Keep in mind HP do not only represent health but also luck, the will to continue fighting, or whatever you want. For this reason a hit dealing 10HP on a lvl 15 Barbarian is not the same thing as 10HP on the lvl 1 Commoner: the first is probably a bruise that doesn't even hurt, the second is a serious wound that can be deadly if not healed right now.
- The PCs as they gain levels quickly become superhumans (the gap being when they reach lvl 6). There is no realism in making them abide to every mere mortals weaknesses.
- As a direct consequence of the previous point: play E6 to make PCs not-so-superhumans.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the Called Shots optional rule. I don't know about 3.5e, but in Pathfinder it's in the Ultimate Combat book, page 193. It discusses losing half your hit points in one blow, and other affects.

> Called Shot: An attack aimed at a body part that deals fewer than 50 points of damage results in a normal called shot.
>
> Critical Called Shot: When a called shot is confirmed as a critical hit but deals fewer than half the creature’s hit points of damage (minimum 50), a critical called shot results.
>
> Debilitating Blow: A called shot that deals half the creature’s hit points of damage (minimum 50) or more (whether a critical hit or not) results in a debilitating blow that has extra effects.
>
> (Pathfinder: Ultimate Combat, pg 194)

It also covers different locations: head, ear, eye, neck, chest, heart, vitals, arm, hand, and leg.

It can also be found here

http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/called-shots/

Comment: That is definitely not what I was looking for. Just a different narrative technique to describe damage.